# Regular Expression formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input box and the condition is to allow the user to enter only numbers, the numbers entered should be in the following format in groups of 4, ex: 4444 5555 and the maximum number of characters to be entered in the textbox should be 9. I am pretty new to regex, so have no clue of how to start. A working sample in fiddle would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is strictly 10 numbers in the above grouping with spaces in the middle, the regex is simple:

```
/^\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}$/
```

Where `\d` means that it would only match a numeric character, `{4}` means that it would look exactly 4 times for the previous match (`\d`), and in this case that would match *4* **numeric characters**. `\s` means one whitespace, and similarly like the `{4}`, `\d{2}` matches 2 numeric characters. The `^` and `$` mean start of the string to be matched and end of the string to be matched respectively.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is fixed then you can just use `\d` to represent a digit

```
/^\d\d\d\d \d\d\d\d \d\d\d\d \d\d$/
```

or use the `{n}` multiplier instead

```
/^\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d\d$/
```

if instead the total length is arbitrary and you just want to be sure that every four digits you have a space things are just slightly more complex:

```
/^(\d{4} )*\d{1,4}$/
```

the meaning is that you want zero or more groups formed with 4 digits and one space followed by 1 to 4 digits. In the last part you can use `{0,4}` if you also want to accept an empty string as a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1 or more of something use '+'.  For example 4+ would be 1 or more consecutive '4's.

Use * to for things that you want 0 or more of!

Use parentheses for groups of characters or groups of other groups.

If you want a space in between, then use the space character between two of them.

It looks like you want 1 or more '4's followed by 0 or more (space followed by 1 or more '4's)

This regular express would match all of the following strings:  "4+( 4+)*"

44444

4 44 4

4 4 4

4

4444444444

4 4

44444444444444 44444444444444444 4444444444444444

4444 4444 44

Answer (score 0):

As per example provided this regex will help

/^[0-9][0-9 ]*$/

This represent numbers with spaces in between. For eg. 444 444. But if you put in this way ' 444 444' like first inserting space then start the numbers then it wont allow.

For that you can use  /^[0-9 ]*$/

^ represent start and $ represent end. So between start and end you can write numbers with spaces.